# PowerShell code help to fetch SQL query data

Tags: sql-server, powershell

PowerShell code to fetch data from multiple SQL servers.

I wanted a code to fetch data based on a SQL query from multiple servers in xls/csv. The SQL query and serverlist to be fetched dynamically using SQL query.

Code:

```cs
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.AnalysisServices") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices") | Out-Null;
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac") | Out-Null

Param(
    [string] $Instance
)
clear
$instance = ''
$cmsserver = 'Raheesh'
$cmsdb = 'msdb'
$BaseDir = 'C:\data\'
$CsvFilePath = $BaseDir + "queryresults.csv"
$ExcelFilePath = $BaseDir + "queryresults.xls"
$ServerNameFile = $BaseDir + "GetServerList.sql"
$ServerListSql = Get-Content($ServerNameFile)
$BackupFile = $BaseDir + "backup.sql"
$BackupSql = Get-Content($BackupFile) | Out-String
$dt = Get-Date
"$Instance fetch starts at " + $dt   +"`r`n" + "`r`n"

# Create your list and place it in a variable using Invoke-Sqlcmd
#Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance <TheNameOfYourCMSServer> -Database msdb (because that is where CMS is stored) -Query $ServerListQuery
$serverlist = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $cmsserver -Database $cmsdb -Query $ServerListSql | Out-String
$serverlist = $serverlist.ToString()
Write-Host $serverlist
Write-Host "enter 1"
# Loop through the list and run your query
foreach ($instance in $serverlist) {
    # remove named instance if it exists for the ping test
    $servername = $instance[0].Split("\") | Select-Object -Index 0 | Out-String  
    Write-Host $servername
    Write-Host "enter 2"
    if (Test-Connection -BufferSize 32 -Count 1 -ComputerName $servername -Quiet) {
        try {
            Write-Host "enter 3"
            # Run the query variable created at the top $SQLServerVersionQuery
            $results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $instance[0] -Query $BackupSql -QueryTimeout 300 | Out-String
            Write-Host "Saving Query Results in CSV format..."
            $results | Export-Csv $CsvFilePath -NoTypeInformation
            (Get-Content $csvFilePath) | Foreach-Object {
                $_ -replace "`"", ""
            } | Set-Content $CsvFilePath
            # Convert CSV file to Excel
            Write-Host "Converting CSV output to Excel..."
            $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
            $excel.Visible = $false
            $excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
            $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($csvFilePath)
            $workSheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
            $resize = $workSheet.UsedRange
            $resize.EntireColumn.AutoFit() | Out-Null
            $xlExcel8 = 56
            $workbook.SaveAs($excelFilePath, $xlExcel8)
            $workbook.Close()
            $excel.Quit()
            $excel = $null
            Write-Host "Results are saved in Excel file: " $excelFilePath
            "$Instance fetch ends at " + $dt   +"`r`n" + "`r`n"
        } catch {
            # Catch the error if SQL connectino doesn't work
            Write-Output "SQL Connect Error on: $instance[0] >> $Error[0]"
        }
    } else {
        # Catch the error if the ping test fails
        Write-Output "Server Ping Error: $servername >> $Error[0]"
    }
}
```

Error:

```
 fetch starts at 02/02/2019 11:00:24


ServerName
----------
raheesh   


enter 1
Method invocation failed because [System.Char] does not contain a method named 'split'.
At C:\Data\PS_OLD\final.ps1:41 char:5
+     $servername = $instance[0].Split("\")  | Select-Object -Index 0 | ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound


enter 2
Test-Connection : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At C:\Data\PS_OLD\final.ps1:44 char:62
+ ... -Connection -BufferSize 32 -Count 1 -ComputerName $servername -Quiet)
+                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Test-Connection], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestConnectionCommand
```

Comment: that error is pretty specific. it means the specific object in `$instance` is NOT a collection. when you use an index on a string, you get a [char]. take a look at the output of this >> `'abc'[0].GetType()`.

Comment: you are welcome ... glad to help a bit & good luck! [*grin*]

Comment: with your tip the split method error is gone but I am getting stuck at below next two steps.(a) Test-Connection -BufferSize 32 -Count 1 -ComputerName $servername -quiet(b)Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $instance -Database $cmsdb -InputFile $BackupFile -QueryTimeout 300  -- i changed to $backupfile here.         The variable $servername and $instance name are resolving to string "***" (servername) properly but not getting applied here.

Comment: i don't know enuf about what `Invoke-SqlCmd` returns to be useful. [*sigh ...*] however, you use `.ToString()` and `Out-String` in   VERY strange ways. it looks like you got back an array of objects ... and then converted them into a string or perhaps a string array. that is truly quite strange. one normally keeps the objects as objects and refers to their properties as needed by dot-notation. at this point, i am stuck ... hopefully someone with access to SQL will drop in and help.

Comment: i got the problem. since i am reading servername though a sql query. the output is getting generated with headername .  hence next steps are not able to identify it ..working on it. lets see

Comment: good! that makes some sense ... objects that contain something other than what you expected - that is a classic source of errors. [*grin*]